# Could not load NIB in bundle - from renaming project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
 reason:'Could not load NIB in bundle:
 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/D8B1E8BA-073B-4E2D-81D3-DAAD4E395CE4/NobleAccelerometer.app> (loaded)' with name 'Gyro2ViewController''
```

I have feeling that it has something do to with the fact that I renamed the project earlier, but I can't find any references using the search function to the old project name.

I don't what else to try.

Comment: *le sigh* Is the view outlet set?

Comment: Does that nib exist, and is it included in the build?

Comment: Is "Gyro2ViewController" the old name or the new name? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the comments above, check that the nib exists in the project, that it has the **EXACT** same name as "**Gyro2ViewController**" and that it's included in the target build phases under "Copy Bundle Resources."

[image: include nib in bundle]

Comment: TigerCoding's answer worked for me. Just as an FYI, make sure the xib is added to the project as well.